# Convert string to date with multiple formats

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have dates in the following format in the same file:

```
"%m/%d/%Y" --> YEAR with 4 digits
"%m/%d/%y" --> YEAR with 2 digits
```

I want to be able to parse both formats. Here's my attempt:

```
df[["field1", "field2"]] = pd.to_datetime(
    df[["field1", "field2"]], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce"
).fillna(pd.to_datetime(df[["field1", "field2"]], format="%m/%d/%y"))
```

But that is not working:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

If I try with only one serie:

```
df["field1"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["field1"], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce"
).fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["field1"], format="%m/%d/%y"))
```

I get ValueError and doesn't seem like both formats are being tested.

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 21
```

What is the most efficient way to use different date formats?

Comment: I think you can leave off the formatting and let pd.to_datetime try its inherit formats and it should decode both %Y and %y correctly. See: `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['01/01/2023', '01/02/23', '12/24/2021', '11/23/21']))`

Comment: Also try this for more than one column: `df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)`

Comment: @ScottBoston you are absolutely right! Just `pd.to_datetime` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Just remove the format parameter from pd.to_datetime and let the inherit formatting handle the change from two digit years to four digit years.

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['01/01/2023', '01/02/23', '12/24/2021', '11/23/21']))
```

Output:

```
0   2023-01-01
1   2023-01-02
2   2021-12-24
3   2021-11-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! I also added the parameter `dayfirst` also just to be more explicit (we know it's the default)